# making chords solid regions in Holoviews chord chart

Tags: matplotlib, holoviews

I'm trying to make the chords between nodes look like solid regions rather than a collection of lines in a holoviews chord chart in the following example:

https://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/route_chord.html

I couldn't find an option to do so in the api. Is there one or is there a programmatic workaround? The only thing I found was to tinker with `edge_line_width` but this value would have to change for different charts.

Comment: Any news on this? I just found out from the [documentation](https://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Chord.html): "The number of chords is scaled by a weight declared as a value dimension on the Chord element." But I don't know how to declare that weight.